How can we add multiple apps under webcredentials in Associated domain file
I want to add my testing app and prod app for release in associated domain file. How can I add them in apple-app-site-association. Can I add both separated by coma
   {
 "webcredentials": {
    "apps": [ "3ABCDEF.com.lalitha.release" ,  3ABCDEF.com.lalitha.test]
 }
}

In Apple documentation example they haven't mention about adding multiple apps under web credentials
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains

Yes, the apps value is an array.
